# Cannot clone repository in Sourcetree because of cygwin1.dll

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I get this error when trying to clone a repository from either BitBucket or Github. I have tried restarting computer, reinstalling Sourcetree, but no luck. Any other tips? There is only one cygwin1.dll file on my computer.

`0 [main] sh (8532) C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1180400/0x1120400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.`

Comment: Do you succeed cloning a repository using the command line, like
```git clone <repository location>```?

Comment: I have embeded GIT in Sourcetree at this point, but the terminal window does not start up, I get an error saying:


`65344 [main] mintty 11228 fork child -1 - forked process 772 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11`

Comment: I think this is related, because the terminal also uses CygWin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I installed GIT in windows and switched from embedded GIT to Windows GIT in SourceTree. Worked like a charm!

Comment: you save me! use windows git!